# How to get values for different rows and multiple columns in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to get data from three different tables

Table 1 : iep_start_lp_request

| lp_id | certifications_check | EmpName | EmpOldID | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6516 | yes | A Hemalatha | 113111 | 2022-01-20 08:55:27 |
| 6332 | yes | A V Shruthi | 110816 | 2022-01-20 08:55:27 |
| 6503 | no | A. Divya | 117909 | 2022-02-20 08:55:27 |
| 11989 | yes | Aabha Verma | 110415 | 2022-02-20 08:55:27 |
| 6401 | no | Aadarsh Keerti | 115899 | 2022-03-20 08:55:27 |
| 8864 | yes | Aakanksha Rehan | 2150618 | 2022-03-20 08:55:27 |
| 8786 | yes | Aakarsh Bhatia | 110081 | 2022-05-20 08:55:27 |

Table2 : iep_employee_list

| EmpName | EmpOldID |
| --- | --- |
| A Hemalatha | 108782 |
| A Hemalatha | 113111 |
| A Hemalatha | 110421 |
| A R Shashikumar | 118531 |
| A S Kundana Sai | 115788 |
| A Satheesh | 112663 |
| A Suresh | 117851 |
| A Umiya Begum | 112956 |
| A V Ramanathan | 116010 |
| A V Shruthi | 110816 |
| A. Divya | 117909 |

Table 3 : iep_postmeta

| post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8865 | select_category | a:1:{i:0;s:18:"AWS Certifications";} |
| 8603 | select_category | a:1:{i:0;s:21:"Google Certifications";} |
| 6656 | select_category | a:1:{i:0;s:24:"Microsoft Certifications";} |

I need to get count of employees who completed different category certifications in each month

[image: Result to get]

Below is the query I tried

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( certicatname.`meta_value`,':"',-1) ,'";}',1)
    as 'certicatname',
       max(case when (lp2.`created_date` BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2022-01-01') then COUNT(lp2.`user_emp_id`) end) as Jan,
       max(case when (lp2.`created_date` BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-04-01') then COUNT(lp2.`user_emp_id`) end) as Feb,
       max(case when (lp2.`created_date` BETWEEN '2022-12-01' AND '2022-08-01') then COUNT(lp2.`user_emp_id`) end) as mar
    
    from
    `iep_start_lp_request` as lp2 LEFT JOIN `iep_employee_list` as emplyoee2 ON lp2.`user_emp_id`=emplyoee2.`EmpOldID` LEFT JOIN `iep_postmeta` as certicatname ON certicatname.`post_id`=lp2.`lp_id` WHERE (certicatname.`meta_value` REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"AWS Certifications".*' OR certicatname.`meta_value` REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"Microsoft Certifications".*' OR certicatname.`meta_value` REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"Google Certifications".*' ) AND lp2.`certifications_check`='yes' GROUP BY certicatname.`meta_value` ORDER BY certicatname.`meta_value`;
```

Comment: Can you share your data as text not photos, this will help us to help you

Comment: How to format tables in question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow and on-line tool https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: hi @SelVazi I have now updated the question to have tables as text, could you please help now, Thanks

Comment: 4.01, 5.50, 7.39 don't appear to be counts of certifications. In Maths, counts are integer-valued. Update your expected output to reflect your description (or the opposite), and use text-formatted tables instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
select
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( ip.meta_value,':"',-1) ,'";}',1) as certificate,
  coalesce(count(case when month(isr.created_date) = 1 then 1 end), 0) as JAN,
  coalesce(count(case when month(isr.created_date) = 2 then 1 end), 0) as FEB,
  coalesce(count(case when month(isr.created_date) = 3 then 1 end), 0) as MARS
from iep_start_lp_request isr
inner join iep_employee_list iel on iel.EmpOldID = isr.EmpOldID
inner join iep_postmeta ip on ip.iep_postmeta = isr.lp_id
where isr.certifications_check = 'yes'
group by ip.meta_value, month(isr.created_date);
```

I used almost same logic as yours :
`SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get certificate name, `case when` to generate columns from rows.
and if we want data based on certificate and month then we need to group by both not only certificate.

You can try it from here https://dbfiddle.uk/l-PV7_zj

Comment: hey @SelVazi, Thank you :) this worked for me with some minor modifications based on my table names :)

Comment: Glad to hear that .. enjoy coding :)